# Generic error occurred in GDI+, when taking a screenshot using Selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium

The Scenario is ,I want to Capture Screenshot & save it to another machine located at same network, for this first I use,

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

Then I Convert it to image file and save it as ".png" format

```
 bitmap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

**filepath includes:"\Machinename\imagefilename.png"**

but at this line i received a exception :"**A generic error occurred in gdi+**"

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a couple of similar looking errors lately, and they were solved simply by passing a correct path to `bitmap.Save()`. Therefore my advice is to first trying to save the file to some very simple, hard-coded path to see if that works. If it does, then you know that it is the filePath that's going wrong. The folder where you are trying to save must exist.

If this doesn't help, then I'd like to see some more code.

Comment: Yes...I found that,the main problem is of Permission.because screenshot is saving on my local machine.                           anyway thanks JoriO for your time

Comment: Ok, file write permission issue belongs to the same family. My opinion is that the exception should be giving us a better hint of where the problem is.